# Bars and stars with two constraints

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that you have to count the number of ways you can add three integers to give n, i.e $i+2j+3k=n$. This is similar to the problem of bars and stars, if the three numbers didn't have any coefficient, then the number of ways is
$$\binom{n+2}{n}.$$
However, I am interested in the case with the coefficients. How reduces the number of ways introducing these two constraints?

Comment: So you have $n=n_1+2n_1+3n_1=6n_1$ and can just solve for $n_1$, yes?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I had posed it wrongly. Now it is corrected.